# Install problems HP Envy 745 desktop

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, hp

I have a HP Envy 745 desktop that runs Windows 10. I was interested in running current version of Ubuntu on but have run into problems. Has anyone done an install on this device?

I have the following problems with the LiveCD and install

1. No wireless so I can't grab updates or anything as I don't have a wired connection in my office and don't have time to run one.
2. The only partition the install shows is the USB disk I've booted on. Is there a hard drive driver I need to load?

I googled ubuntu install hp envy 745 but couldn't find any step by step or something

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify on point 2? If you can, boot the liveCD, and select "Try Ubuntu" instead of install. Then find the applications menu in the upper left, and search for and open GParted. Select your internal hard drive from the upper right of the window. Then reopen the applications, and find the application named `Screenshot` or something like that. Take a screenshot of GParted and post it here.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear and I'll upload a screenshot later. I was just doing an install and the only disk to select during the installation was the USB drive I had booted off and not the hard disk.
I'll give it a shot in the morning

Comment: Oh, sorry for the overly-long explanation, I thought this was your first time using Ubuntu and didn't notice the 1,000+ rep :)

Comment: No harm no foul. It's been a while since I've been a Ubuntu user though so probably making some rookie mistakes again :)

Comment: Follow up on the hard drive side of the house, when I run gparted I get an error message that says:
"Could not stat device /dev/mapper/lsw: untested metadata version 1.4.01 found on /dev/sda - No such file or directory"

Since I don't have wifi I can't post the screenshot. 

Also any ideas on the wifi side of the house? What should I look for there as well?

Comment: I think the problem with the hard disk involves RST and that I need to turn that off. I didn't get that notification until I walked thru the installer again: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347